# Div overlay on top of centered images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to overlay a div (or a span) on an image that is stacked on top of another image. Both images are  centered and scaled to fit. My images have a higher height than width, but they are not fixed in size. I would like the div to fit exactly the **higherImg** (i.e. have same dimensions and position as **higherImg** even when scaling takes place).

I am a beginner in CSS, so all I could manage is stack the images like this:

```css
.imgbox {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.lowerImg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 85vh;
  z-index: 3;
}

.higherImg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 60vh;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 4;
}

.topDiv {
  background: $pink-color;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 5px;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="imgbox">
    <img class="lowerImg" />
    <img class="higherImg" />
    <div class="topDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle link please?

Comment: might also be helpful to make an image of what you would like the output to be - I'm not sure what you mean by 3 images overlayed on a div - do you want them to touch, or evenly spaced out.. there are many options.

Comment: @nycynik There are only 2 images and a div. The div overlayed on top of an image which is on top of another image. So, in the descending z-order: div, higherImg, lowerImg.

Comment: you want things to stack upon each other in the same order? if not what should be the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood ti correctly, you want the div and img to stack upon each other:

something like this?

```css
.imgbox {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: default;
}

.topDiv {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.lowerImg {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
}

.higherImg {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: default;
  transition: opacity .8s;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="imgbox">
    <div class="topDiv">
      <img class="lowerImg" src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" />
      <img class="higherImg" src="http://placekitten.com/201/201" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both images (and implicitly the topDiv) should scale to fit more or less the screen, so I don't want to use fixed width and height for any of them.

Comment: They should also be always centered, so I don't want to use absolute top, right etc.

Comment: those width and height is just an example, so that you can change the height and width as you want, I moved your code to snippet and it doesn't help what you're seeking. hence I give color and height width for those elements

Comment: @Copiltembel I have removed height and width property added 2 images for the img tag, because without image you won't see the difference, so now you may able to view it full screen.

Comment: Thanks, but one problem is that the topDiv has a larger size than the higherImg. What I would like is that the topDiv will have exactly the same dimensions as the higherImg, and completely overlap it.

Comment: @Copiltembel done. that was because to differentiate I added `top`, `padding` and `border` to it, you can see now it is of same dimension of `higherimg` and fitted exactly same.

Comment: Not sure I got it right. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29etn78L/ The cursor: crosshair; should only be visible over the topmost image, which is not. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: One thing to mention you have have inline-elements within block but not vice versa like you can have `img` inside `div` not the other way. if you want the div to be within the img then you have to first wrap an extra div around img and then assign width and height to it.

Comment: I can change the html, that's not a problem. Whatever it takes to achieve the goal.

Comment: @Copiltembel check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/xsoj65dm/22/

Comment: Almost there! The only thing now is that if the whole container is shrink (like when dragging the edge of the container in jsfiddle), such that the higherImg is scaled down, the div still covers the whole imgbox.

Comment: That is because of width and height auto, since you want the image to fit , so when you shrink the size it indeed gets shrinked.

Comment: Yes, so I would like the topDiv to shrink at the same time with the higherImg

Comment: if you talking about only topDiv and HigherImg then it is working as expected, another image you see is from the low img, so the shrink is happening for both topDiv and Shrink. Like this is the example : http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/xsoj65dm/40/

Comment: Man, I think you're super close with the last fiddle. It's just that the higherImg should also shrink if the container shrinks (just like it's happening with the lowerImg).

Comment: Lol, I hope. ok here the the latest fiddle, where both image shrink and expand as single: Hope this is what you need, I have updated same as answer as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/xsoj65dm/79/